# Are the Alt+Ctl+FN key combinations (aka srvrkeys) hardcoded into Xorg?

Tags: linux, xorg, keyboard-shortcuts, console

Are the `Alt+Ctl+FN` key combinations (aka srvrkeys) hardcoded into Xorg?

[This question](https://superuser.com/questions/231798/how-to-send-ctrlaltf1-and-other-special-keystrokes-to-x-window) explains how to turn them on and off (I already knew that, just mentioning it to show I have done my homework). But what I need now is to keep the feature but bound to different key combinations, perhaps just `Alt+FN` like the usual Linux VT bindings. Possible?

The reason is that on my preferred leop^H^H^H^Hkeyboard the `Alt+Ctl+FN` combinations effectively don't exist :-(.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are the Alt+Ctl+FN key combinations (aka srvrkeys) hardcoded into Xorg?

No, they're not. They can be configured via [Xkb](https://www.x.org/wiki/XKB/). But understanding how to effectively and correctly configure Xkb would take someone more than a lifetime ;-).

But as a simple hack, completely client-side, this should allow you to switch with just `Alt-F1` instead of `Ctrl-Alt-F1` [See the diff at the end if your layout is so different that the `ed` script doesn't work]:

```
xkbcomp $DISPLAY - > xkb
cp xkb xkb~
ed xkb <<EOT
/type "CTRL+ALT"/
/Level5/s/Control+//p
w
EOT
xkbcomp - $DISPLAY < xkb
```

However, notice that your desktop environment may override your changes. Also,  just `Alt-Backspace` (a common keybinding in some editors) instead of `Ctrl-Alt-Backspace` may kill your X11 server, if you have that option enabled (look for `Terminate_Server` in the generated `xkb` file above).

```
diff xkb~ xkb
...
@@ -376,15 +376,15 @@
     type "CTRL+ALT" {
         modifiers= Shift+Control+Alt+LevelThree;
         map[Shift]= Level2;
         preserve[Shift]= Shift;
         map[LevelThree]= Level3;
         map[Shift+LevelThree]= Level4;
         preserve[Shift+LevelThree]= Shift;
-        map[Control+Alt]= Level5;
+        map[Alt]= Level5;
         level_name[Level1]= "Base";
         level_name[Level2]= "Shift";
         level_name[Level3]= "Alt Base";
         level_name[Level4]= "Shift Alt";
         level_name[Level5]= "Ctrl+Alt";
     };
     type "LOCAL_EIGHT_LEVEL" {
```

Comment: Thanks, that is very helpful though not a final solution for me because I need to preserve Alt+Backspace and such.

Comment: Perhaps I should mention that I already hack my xkb settings some, therefore I'm not as afraid of xkb as you might think :-P

Comment: @q.undertow Changing the `type=` of `key <BKSP>` to `"FOUR_LEVEL_ALPHABETIC"` and removing the `Terminate_Server` from its row would probably do (untested).